# Storing enormously large arrays

Tags: java, arrays, overflow, physics, modeling

I have a problem. I work in Java, Eclipse. My program calculates some mathematical physics, and I need to draw animation (Java SWT package) of the process (some hydrodynamics). The problem is 2D, so each iteration returns two dimensional array of numbers. One iteration takes rather long time and time needed for iteration changes from one iteration to another, so showing pictures dynamically as program works seems like a bad idea. In this case my idea was to store a three dimensional array, where third index represents time, and building an animation when calculations are over. But in this case, as I want accuracuy from my program, I need a lot of iterations, so program easily reaches maximal array size. So the question is: how do I avoid creating such an enormous array or how to avoid limitations on array size? I thought about creating a special file to store data and then reading from it, but I'm not sure about this. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: How much memory do you have? I bet you'll run out of memory before you come across array size limitations. You could try a distributed solution such as memcached/redis, but you'll have to try to come up with a cleverer data structure than just an array.

Comment: @instop:Give it a try, if it works then ok otherwise come again. At least try some.

Comment: I don't recommend adding dimensions to your array. While they are easier to read, they abstract away from the data; every abstraction costs performance. Use raw binary data if you have the option and do everything you can to only load what you need. Run a few iterations and store a few 'frames' of time in a file and repeat with a new file. To display, load the first existing file and display them in order until you run out of complete files to display.

Comment: Essentially, apply the concept of divide & conquer.

Comment: Have you tried writing the data to the disk and then postproprocessing it into an animation? Disk space is cheap nowadays and if your output is a fixed size array, seeking to the correct record is easy. If not, simply write the offsets into a separate index file.

Answer (score 0):

When I was working on a procedural architecture generation system at university for my dissertation I created small, extremely easily read and parsed binary files for calculated data.  This meant that the data could be read in within an acceptable amount of time, despite being quite a large amount of data...

I would suggest doing the same for your animations... It might be of value storing maybe five seconds of animation per file and then caching each of these as they are about to be required...

Also, how large are your arrays, you could increase the amount of memory your JVM is able to allocate if it's not maximum array size, but maximum memory limitations you're hitting.

I hope this helps and isn't just my ramblings...